# cannot require ruby wordnet gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, wordnet

I installed ruby gem 'wordnet', a gem on English linguistic. After I installed it (wordnet 0.0.5), when I tried to require it using irb, I got the following errors:

```
>> require 'wordnet'
LoadError: no such file to load -- bdb
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/wordnet-0.0.5/lib/wordnet/lexicon.rb:34
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/wordnet-0.0.5/lib/wordnet.rb:83
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:32:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:638
```

how to solve this and make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the wordnet gem is requiring the Berkley DB library.  Try to do a

```
gem install bdb
```

and then try again.

Comment: Try installing `libdb4.8-dev` from your package manager then reinstalling the gem. Personally this got me past the native library error but I got another error `extconf.rb:25:in `initialize': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)` but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get past this problem with the following:

```
$ brew install berkeley-db
```

Then got the bdb from here: https://github.com/knu/ruby-bdb

```
$ ruby extconf.rb --with-db-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db/5.1.19
$ make 
$ install
$ gem install bdb
```

now I can require 'wordnet'

Answer (score 3):

Getting the wordnet gem running properly is a little tricky. I finally got it working after a lot of trail and error.

I wrote down all the steps I took in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1779371

You should be able to grab what you need from there to get it running.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling require 'rubygems' and then require 'wordnet'

See if that works.

Also, make sure you have the latest version of Xcode from Apple installed. That comes with some Ruby dependencies.